# How can I change the browser home page in Steam?

Tags: steam

Every time I open up the browser from within a game in Steam, I am taken to Google. I would much rather this site be the home page of the Steam web browser. I can't seem to figure out how to change it, however.

How do I set the home page of the Steam web browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The placement of the setting to change the homepage has been changed after the last answer posted here (July 26 2012). It is now located in the "Web Browser" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Actually you very much can...just go to Settings > In-Game > Browser Homepage.

[image: Where to find this option]

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer. Image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WxdyJ.png

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this had changed since I answered the question!

Answer (score 3):

Support for changing the homepage location was added in a [patch to the Steam client](http://store.steampowered.com/news/7524/) on March 14th, 2012.

This option is now on the In-Game tab of the Settings dialog.

(When this question was asked, the only way to customize the homepage was to change your iGoogle settings, as the overlay browser always took you to Google.com)

Comment: You can also add a custom button to the overlay like suggested here that points to whatever url you want: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=19386991&postcount=20