# How can I have game-specific Steam in-game browser homepages?

Tags: steam

It seems the option to set the homepage for Steam's in-game browser only allows for one URL. That said, I would like to know if there is a way to enable a different homepage for different games. For example, I'd like to have a CS:GO esports site as my homepage when CS:GO is running, but want something like Destiny Item Manager as my homepage when Destiny 2 is running.

Is there any way I can have game-specific Steam in-game browser homepages? Note that this is different from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37792/how-can-i-change-the-browser-home-page-in-steam/242061) which only addresses the default homepage across the entirety of Steam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[custeam.io](https://custeam.io/) as the overlay homepage will automatically show a page for any Steam-based game you play. You can also add bookmarks and game-specific notes. IDK if you can setup your own homepage on a per-game basis with it as-is, but you may be able to play with it and make that possible if you're into computer programming.